# In C# VS2008 how to replace (string)aaa to aaa.ToString()

Tags: c#, vb.net

I just converted a VB.net solution into C# solution. But lots of variables have been coverted like:

```
string var1 = (string)1;
string var2 = (string)intVar; //intVar is a int value
```

I just want to convert all `(string)XXXX` to `XXXX.ToString()` by using some Regular expressions or some other replace methods.

Can someome help me out?

Comment: Is it just a code formatting issue then, or is there a problem with the (string) casts?

Comment: It is a problem with the (string) casts: Cannot cast expression of type 'int' to type 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to use this one

Find: \(string\){(.*)}{:Po}

Replace: \1.ToString()\2

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

find:  **\(string\){:a*}**
replace: **\1.ToString()**

Back up your solution first!

Comment: You have to escape the brackets, which didn't show up in the answer.  fixed.

Comment: Thanks Will! Your solution is great for original question. But I found there are some other cases:

Something like :

attbXML.InnerText = (string)oField.Type;

i have to convert to :
attbXML.InnerText = oField.Type.ToString();

Do you think it is possible?

Comment: You can switch :a* for [:a\.]*

Answer (score 3):

The text editor [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net) has regular expression support. You may try something like: Replace `[(]string[)][ ]*([^ .\t;/]*)` with `\1.ToString()`.

This turns this:

```
(string) xyz;
(string) abc.123;
(string)alf;
(string)argu ment
```

into this:

```
xyz.ToString();
abc.ToString().123;
alf.ToString();
argu.ToString() ment
```

This however, does not handle the case of `(string) aFunction( obj1, obj2 )`.

You may want to handle these by yourself first, or build another regexp.

Comment: Comments for what's wrong with this would be helpful. I believe this addresses the OP's question, and provides caveats, and has been edited several times as new caveats are found.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that he was asking about doing this in VS, which is not notepad++.  Plus VS' regex is messed up, so standard regex won't work.

Comment: Well, the question asks "How to I convert all (string)aaa to aaa.ToString()".. so, was addressing that. It's like the old "My car won't start. I need gas." Then getting heck when I give you gas but your car won't start. Another question may be in order. But I still gave you the gas. :-) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No, the question asks "In C# VS2008 how to replace (string)aaa to aaa.ToString()"  As in, In C# VS2008.  If you've never had to deal with VS regexes you wouldn't appreciate the difference that makes.  And, believe me, it does!

Comment: Thank you. I will surely read up on those. I always look forward to learning new technologies and isms. Yet another window has opened up for me to learn some more about Visual Studio. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you really want to do this as a mass conversion.  As in all reality in your example, you should end up with the following.

```
string var1 = "1";
```

and

```
string var2 = intVar.ToString();
```

There is no need for your first example to be doing a cast, when it can be a string from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with regex but I offer a warning instead. You might not want to replace all (string)xxx to xxx.toString() because (as you know I am sure) (string) is casting and a ToString() is a method call. You can only cast something as string if the object is a descendant of string. You can call ToString() if the implementor of the class overrode the ToString() method. If not then you are just going to get the default implementation.

Comment: In my solution most of cases are convert int value into string value. So my question is how to convert (string)intValue into format intValue.ToString(). It may give me some errors but totally the compilling errors will decrease tremendous

Comment: I agree that fixing the build errors is good, but, the other issue, as this poster and myself have pointed out, will go un-noticed if you simply use a find/replace method.

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted but so have upvoted it in support :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason that you get the extra code in the conversion, is that you don't have `Option Strict On` in the VB code. If you had, you wouldn't be able to do those implicit conversions in the first place.

So, the VB code should look like this, and the C# code would then look right in the conversion:

```
var1 As String = "1"

var2 As String = intVar.ToString
```

To fix this after the conversion is done is quite beyond what a regular expression is capable of. Sure, you could make an expression that would convert all `(string)x` to `x.ToString()`, but that would probably cause more problems that it fixed...